# Writing an LLVM Pass 

Tags: optimization, llvm, clang, bytecode

i'm trying to create an LLVM pass using the guide at http://llvm.org/releases/2.9/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html
but i'm having several problems:

- i haven't many of the folder that are indicated into the guide (lib/Transform/Hello) and (Debug+Asserts), i have created them, is it right? what's the right path?
  i create these: /usr/lib/llvm-2.9/lib/Transforms/Hello     and   /usr/lib/llvm-2.9/Debug+Asserts
- when i try to make the file in the guide i have error:

.

```
# Makefile for hello pass


# Path to top level of LLVM heirarchy
LEVEL = /usr/lib/llvm-2.9/build        #*********I MODIFY THIS!!!! ***************

# Name of the library to build
LIBRARYNAME = Hello

# Make the shared library become a loadable module so the tools can 
# dlopen/dlsym on the resulting library.
LOADABLE_MODULE = 1

# Tell the build system which LLVM libraries your pass needs. You'll probably
# need at least LLVMSystem.a, LLVMSupport.a, LLVMCore.a but possibly several
# others too.
LLVMLIBS = LLVMCore.a LLVMSupport.a LLVMSystem.a

# Include the makefile implementation stuff
include $(LEVEL)/Makefile.common
```

and i modify also other lines into Makefile.common:

```
ifndef LLVM_SRC_ROOT
include $(LEVEL)/Makefile.rules
else
include $(LLVM_SRC_ROOT)/Makefile.rules
endif
```

because it doesn't find the Makefile.rules (in this way it works)

but now i have this error when i do make into the folder containing my hello.c file (/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/lib/Transforms/Hello):

```
make: ***  No rule to make target "/configure", needed by "/config.status".  Stop.
```

what's the problem?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, it seems you're trying to develop using the binary of the libraries. Unfortunately, this won't work. You need to download sources, build them and then start developing your own pass.

Also, 2.9 is already too ancient. Consider at least upgrading to 3.0 release.

Comment: i read this somewhere:
"# do NOT set LLVMLIBS, the LLVM documentation has this wrong
#LLVMLIBS = LLVMCore.a LLVMSupport.a LLVMSystem.a"   
is it true?       what do you mean with "You need to download sources, build them", where can i download them?

Comment: ok, thank you!!, but now i have another problem, i receive this error when i try to do make: ../../../Makefile.common:61: ../../../Makefile.config: No such file or directory
../../../Makefile.common:69: /Makefile.rules: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/Makefile.rules'.  Stop.
i read another post with this question but i don't understand how to solve

Comment: Do not forget to run configure before make.

Comment: however now it should be right when i do make for the pass example http://llvm.org/releases/2.9/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html instead i receive this error: ~/llvm-3.0.src/lib/Transforms/Hello$ make
llvm[0]: Compiling Hello.cpp for Release build (PIC)
Hello.cpp:20:10: error: use of class template RegisterPass requires template arguments
  static RegisterPass X("hello", "Hello World Pass", false, false);
         ^
In file included from Hello.cpp:1:
In file included from /home/nichis/llvm-3.0.src/include/llvm/Pass.h:368:

Comment: /home/nichis/llvm-3.0.src/include/llvm/PassSupport.h:198:8: note: template is declared here
struct RegisterPass : public PassInfo {
       ^
Hello.cpp:20:23: error: excess elements in scalar initializer
  static RegisterPass X("hello", "Hello World Pass", false, false);
                      ^        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
why?

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks, using the llvm-3.0 documentation the example file is a little bit different, now it works (it create the Hello.so file into llvm-3.0.src/Release/lib (and not Debug+Asserts) ), even if now there is another error when i try to do the "opt - load ......" command: "Error opening '../../../Release/lib/Hell...... Undefined symbol: _ZN4llvm12PassRegistry12registerPassERKNS_8PassInfoEb"  do you know why?

Comment: maybe because for creating the Hello.bc file i use llvm-clang instead of llvm-gcc? (this guide says to use llvm-gcc but it doesn'n work: http://llvm.org/releases/3.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#tutorial) or maybe because i have opt version 2.8 while i'm using llvm-3.0 ?

Comment: ok, i solved all! :) ... i was still having llvm-2.9 and llvm-2.8 on my pc. now i have only the llvm-3.0, i recreate the .bc file and now it works! :) Thankyou

Comment: Ok. Make sure you not only changed the title, but also "accept" an answer.